# Select a module to build an ad or job search site

Tags: webforms

Select a module to build an ad or job search site

I want to create a site for job search and employment in the field of employer and contractor

I can

1. create an information submission forum with the webform module
   (Use the webform module and display submission forms by a view module
   )
   2.Or I can create a new content from the structure and add new content to an information submission form
   Or other solutions

My question is which method is better for SEO?

Answer (score 2):

In short: New content will simpler and better for SEO, because webform submissions require additional handling for SEO.

For content submission, you should:

1. Allow required roles (guest or authorized) to submit content form in User permissions page.
2. Use [Content Workflow](https://drupalize.me/topic/content-workflow) for controlling submitted content (draft, published statuses).
3. Control SEO of that content by Drupal core and [these modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2571379).

p.s. I recommend using both (hard way, but protected, and IMHO, preferred):

1. Webform for collection information. Also, it allows building powerful forms: multistep, grouped fields, messages and so on without programming.
2. New content that show information. This allows you to use SEO modules, that usually work with content types.
   Webform allow easily control information control, so you will protect from spam, unusable, "broken" form submissions. That allow to reduce "New content" creation.
   New content, that created after submission - programmatically, [Rules Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_webform) or  [Webform Content Creator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_content_creator) modules.